# What is the DC to break a tree?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, difficulty-class

A high-strength character (D&D 3.5) attempts to snap a tree or thick branch in half across their knee, or kick a tree down in the forest. This is not dealing damage, this is clearly a Strength check versus some DC, similar to kicking down a door. What is the RAW DC to break a tree? How does this change based on the tree's diameter?

Comment: Don't believe there are any sources for a tree's break DC, but I wrote [this answer about break DCs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164497/break-dc-too-low/165049#165049) not too long ago, and this may give some perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Break DC 25 to 35 depending on diameter

A "Small Tree" appears in *Anauroch: The Empire of Shade*, p.119. It is one foot thick, with an AC of 4, hardness 5, 150 hit points, and a break DC of 25.

"Dead Trees" appear in *Dragon* magazine #360, p.55, with the same statistics.

A "Large Tree" appears in *Fortress of the Yuan-Ti*, page 29. It is five feet thick, with an AC of 3, hardness 5, 600 hit points, and a break DC of 35.

Naturally, the break DC could be higher or lower for trees which are thicker or thinner than normal, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The Rules Compendium makes the following comment:

> BREAKING OBJECTS
>   When a creature tries to break something with sudden force rather than by dealing damage, use a Strength check (including a modifier due to size) to see whether it succeeds. *The DC depends more on the construction of the item than 
>   on the material.*

**Emphasis mine**

In other words, it seems that one is finding the weak point in the construction of the composite object, not necessarily actually breaking a given material. Doors are typically built from multiple parts, after all. And doors are the majority of examples in the list.

It then proceeds to give a list of examples, none of which are a tree. However, if you could find something which is close to the construction of a tree on the list, the DM might be willing to adhoc the DC.

The highest DC given is 28, for a stone door, iron door, and masterwork manacles.